# LinkedIn Integration flow using Spring social

Tags: linkedin-api, spring-social

I am trying to provide get access to LinkedIn data in a Spring-based web application.The idea is to connect to a LinkedIn account, get LinkedIn data(education or employer information for argument sake) & show that data on my application's page. Now I studied a bit on Spring Social   OAUTH abstraction for LinkedIn(using spring-social-linkedin) and also read some code samples for accessing data but I am still unable to wrap my head around this flow and how do I write the code for my specific purpose?

1. Do I create a specific web page where user put's in his LinkedIn login details and the ConnectController (already intialized in IOC container) will then take care of the connection?
   If so what will be the action & method values on the Login page?
2. If no login page is to be created, how will LinkedIn account details be inputted by user and How will ConnectController get the account details to authenticate?
3. Once authenticated, how to navigate through user's data?

If someone can explain in a step-by-step manner how to approach my requirement here,would really appreciate it.

Comment: This question is a little broad for an SO question. Try writing some code to start and come back when you have a more specific problem.

Comment: I am basically looking for answers to the 3 questions that I have asked.that should help me understand how the spring-social-integration works in general

Comment: If you narrow this question down you will be much more likely to get some help.